# Oracle 11g Call to undefined function oci_connect()

Tags: php, oracle, oracle11g, wamp, wampserver

I'm trying to make Oracle 11g database work with wamp PHP 5.6 on the x64 version of windows 10.

In the php.ini I was told to uncomment two lines, but I DO NOT EVEN FIND THEM!

```
extension=php_oracle.dll 
extension=php_oci8.dll
```

I do have instantclient_11_2 installed and I think I configured it rather well...

I just can't figure this out..

I'm frustrated, 24 hours I've been trying to fix the problem. Please help, and ask me any more details if you want.

Comment: Have you tried adding those lines to your `php.ini`?

Comment: Yes, but the dll files aren't even there for some reason.

Comment: You have to download them from Oracle, or they could come as part of the Instant Client. They are not a standard part of PHP

Comment: They are a standard of the wamp installation, but they're not here, I downloaded them anyway but it still doesn't work.

Comment: No, depends upon version of WAMPServer. What version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I unistalled the x64 version and installed the x32 and everything worked fine. If you have the same problem, try installing the x32 version! Oh, and make sure you unistall the x64 version properly before installing the other, or your computer is kinda screwed! :D